# Insertar registro de una tabla y pasarla a otra utilizando SORTABLE

Tags: php, jquery, sql, sql-server

Buen día, quiero saber como puedo crear la instrucción para que al mover un registro de una tabla a la otra se inserte en la base de datos utilizando PHP, y JQuery con la libreria sortable, la base de datos es en SQL SERVER, por ahora el codigo solo realiza la funcion de mover los registros correctamente, pero al moverlo de una tabla a otra este no se guarda mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table tbody').sortable({

            update: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).children().each(function(index) {
                    if ($(this).attr('data-position') != (index + 1)) {
                        $(this).attr('data-position', (index + 1)).addClass('updated');
                    }

                });

                saveNewPositions();
            }
        });
    });


    function saveNewPositions() {
        var positions = [];
        $('.updated').each(function() {
            positions.push([$(this).attr('data-index'), $(this).attr('data-position')]);
            $(this).removeClass('updated');
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ruta.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                update: 1,
                positions: positions
            },
            success: function(response) {

            }
        });

    }

    $(function() {
        $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });


</script>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué hacerlo con php y JQuery cuando se puede hacer directamente en la base de datos con T-SQL? Es una sola instrucción y no se requiere de pasar la información de un servidor a otro.

Comment: Me ayudarias mucho si me dijeras como se realiza ese proceso